# Show/hide a div on resize with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div on my page when the page gets below a certain screen width and then show it again if the browser is resized back above the breakpoint.

I am using a script I found online and it works great, but the breakpoint doesn't seem to be working correctly. I set the div to hide if the screen gets below 768px and show if its above 768px but for some reason, it's happening at 784px instead.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //window
    var $window = $(window);

    //display nav
    var displayNav = true;

    //on resize get widths
    getWidths();
    $window.resize(getWidths);

    //set width of content to the needed widths
    function getWidths()
    {
        var browserWidth = $window.width();

        if ((browserWidth <= 768) && (displayNav == true))
        {
            displayNav = false;
            toggleNav();
        }
        else if ((browserWidth > 768) && (displayNav == false))
        {
            displayNav = true;
            toggleNav();
        }
    }

    //toggle nav
    function toggleNav()
    {
        $(".secondaryNav").toggle();
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You dont even need jQuery for this. You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Media Queries will not work because the DIV will not be hidden/shown upon resizing the browser window. I definitely need jQuery for this.

Comment: @APAD1 It is what media quires queries are made for. As you resize the browser it will adjust style according to media queries.

Comment: @APAD1 why that? Have you at least tried it? Media queries are preprocessed, no need to wait for any event

Comment: That is incorrect. If I use media queries and resize the browser to mobile width, the div that is supposed to be hidden will still be visible until the page is refreshed. Trust me, I know what a media query is.

Comment: @APAD1 trust me, you are doing something wrong somewhere else then

Comment: [Not true at all](http://jsfiddle.net/hLaMH/)

Comment: Well you clearly don't. I use a media query on one of the sites I run to hide a hover over "Reviews" tab. As you resize the to where there is no room for the Reviews tab and it is just about to start colliding with other elements it's style is set to display: none; I can drag it back and forth all day. It work every time.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ resize the window and watch media queries hide elements and then show them over and over again.

Comment: You're right, my bad, not sure why it wasn't working before but it is now.

Comment: It's chill man. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight CSS bro.

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .secondaryNav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```